# Request for a word that means a "one single element not separate from each other"

Tags: word-choice, word-request

In the following sentence, what can be used instead of "as one element"? I'm looking for a more academic word. I tend to say that human life and wildlife are not separate and they should be thought as a single unity.

> A more accurate view of wildlife and human life is to see them
> **as one element** with many interconnected and mutually beneficial links
> between them.

Please suggest me a word!

Comment: *indivisible, inextricably linked, part of an integral whole,...*

Comment: I think that in an academic context, you might be better off asking a lecturer or tutor who is a subject matter expert what the jargon of the field you're studying might be, since this might be field-dependent.

Answer (score 15):

While it is marginally longer, I would suggest using **as a single entity**. The word "entity" allows for more complexity than the word element. The end of the sentence should perhaps be recast as well, to avoid the final plural "them" which would naturally refer back to the singular "entity. You would have

> A more accurate view of wildlife and human life is to see them as a single entity with many interconnected and mutually beneficial links between its parts.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [**"holistic"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holistic).

> - relating to or concerned with wholes or with complete systems rather than with the analysis of, treatment of, or dissection into parts
> - relating to or concerned with complete systems rather than with individual parts
>
> ***// holistic ecology** views humans and the environment as a single system* (Merriam-Webster)

> A more accurate view of wildlife and human life is to see them as a holistic ecology  with many interconnected and mutually beneficial links between them.

Comment: Holisticly certainly satisfies the "academic-sounding" part. Everyone knows what it means (more-or-less), but no one uses it in ordinary conversation.

Answer (score 6):

You might have to adjust the sentence structure a little, but: **system**.

From Merriam-Webster: "a regularly interacting or interdependent group of items forming a unified whole".

Comment: That was my idea as well: As opposed to "unit" or "entity", *system* doesn't hide the fact that the .. errr ... *entity* we're discussing has an internal structure with discernible, interacting ... *components.* That's exactly what the OP describes with "many interconnected and mutually beneficial links between its parts" (even if in all honestly we should admit that not all links are beneficial, as the Mammoths could confirm if they were still around ;-).)

Answer (score 4):

You could say that wildlife and human life are **[symbiotic](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/symbiotic)**, meaning a close, prolonged association between two or more different organisms of different species. It can also imply a mutually beneficial dependence.

Answer (score 2):

I would actually encourage you not to change your phrasing because you want a more academic word. "Element" is academic enough already, but that really doesn't matter. You want words that are clear and precise, and it is nice if they are vivid, but, in academic prose, clarity and precision are more important.

I notice that some answers that have been given focus more on the interconnections and mutual benefit, suggesting words like "symbiosis". But my impression is that you are more talking about categories, and that there should be one category of life, not human life and wildlife. In that case "category" isn't a bad choice of word. Peter's suggestion of "entity" and your own original "element" are good too.

Answer (score 1):

The term that is generally used for this is an [ecosystem](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ecosystem). Here is the definition:

> all the living things in an area and the way they affect each other and the environment

> A more accurate view of wildlife and human life is to see them as an **ecosystem** with many interconnected and mutually beneficial links between them

Comment: This actually seems to be the best, since that's what "ecosystem"  means.  It's so misused these days to mean something like "product line" that it's a pleasant change to see it used correctly. meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word "monad" or the phrase "monistic whole".

[https://duckduckgo.com/?q=monad+def&ia=definition](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=monad%20def&ia=definition)

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/monistic

The idea is taken from philosophy, and even though you aren't talking about mind, substances, etc., it might accurately convey what I think you are trying to say.
So, you could say something like:

> A more accurate view of wildlife and humans is to see them as a **monad/monistic whole (choose one)** with many interconnected and mutually beneficial links between them.

Answer (score 0):

Commensal. It doesn't imply quite such an obligate dependency as symbiosis, and literally means "eating at the same table".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensalism

Answer (score 0):

Symbiotic has a very specific scientific meanings, which you may or may not want.  Commensal is more general but not widely used or understood.

A more general word which is used in many contexts is "interdependent".

Lots of others to consider:
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/interdependent

Answer (score 0):

> A more accurate view of wildlife and human life is to see them as ***one nature*** (or as ***having the same nature***) with many interconnected and mutually beneficial links between them.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nature) says that

> the force that is responsible for physical life is often called ***nature***.

However, I have a problem with the rest of the sentence. Once you state their oneness, it is strange to describe this oneness with "connections between them" in this way. It is as if you said:

> ***This one nature has*** many interconnected and mutually beneficial links ***between them***.

I would transform the phrase into a different clause showing cause or reason:

> A more accurate view of wildlife and human life is to see them as one nature, ***having/ as they have*** many interconnected and mutually beneficial links between them.

A relative sentence would also be an option:

> A more accurate view of wildlife and human life is to see them as one nature, ***within which/wherein they have*** many interconnected and mutually beneficial links between them.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the word monolithic

Comment: But that it is exactly not. The man-nature ... *thing* ... is a heterogeneous system.